# Opposite for "gold standard" for a benchmark of awfulness

Tags: phrase-requests, antonyms

A metaphorical meaning of "gold standard" is something that is really good to be compared with. For example, Wiktionary says

> 2. (idiomatic) A test or measure of comparison that is considered ultimate or ideal.
>
>    > The OED is the gold standard for English dictionaries. Everyone wants to see how their version measures up to that ideal.

Is there an example of a benchmark of awfulness, such that if something is worse than item X, then it is very bad?

An example of how this would be used is

> Recently, Kazakhstan has become the _____ for backwardness, with news articles saying that [Australia's education system](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2016-11-30/australia-declines-in-global-education-report/8077474) or [internet speed](http://www.smh.com.au/business/consumer-affairs/australia-s-broadband-slower-than-kazakhstan-20180107-p4yyb1.html) is worse than Kazakstan's.

Neither [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/gold_standard), the gold standard in dictionaries, nor [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gold_standard) mentions any antonyms.

Comment: @Downvoter is there additional research I should have done?

Comment: Are you looking for a phrase that suggests that the thing in question really is the worst of its type, or a phrase that suggests that people are measuring badness against it? Those aren't necessarily the same thing.

Comment: Avoid answering questions in comments. Post comments here only to [ask for more information or suggest improvements](/help/privileges/comment). Other types of comment can be posted in the [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) or a chatroom created for the purpose.

Comment: @AlexP Do not give answers in comments.

Comment: Downvoter was probably a fan of Borat the movie, I upvoted to balance it out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## *Lead Standard*

Recently the term ***lead standard*** has been used to contrast with *gold standard*. For example, the authors of a 2015 *Queensland Times* article, [“Integration, assimilation should be gold standard”](https://www.qt.com.au/news/reader-integration-assimilation-should-be-gold-sta/2850805/), write:

> High concentrations of people in one suburb all maintaining a different language, culture and some religious practices is a problem. Add high unemployment and welfare dependence and this is the "**lead standard**" that is causing a lot of problems in Europe.

In this syndicated 2017 article from Raycom News Network, [“Lee Zurik Investigation: Gold standard for ethics, **lead standard** for enforcement”](http://raycomgroup.worldnow.com/story/24075522/zurik-ethics-fines), then-State Treasurer John Kennedy is quoted saying:

> Kennedy says, "One of the things I took away from your series is, you can argue about whether Louisiana has a gold standard of ethics laws. But no reasonable person could argue that our standard of enforcement is anything more than, I don't know, lead or tin."

In this 2013 article on [“Screening for Post-Traumatic Stress Disorder (PTSD) in Primary Care”](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK126690/) from the US Department of Veterans Affairs we read:

> Non-independent comparisons of signs and symptoms with a standard of uncertain validity (which may even “incorporate” the sign or symptom result in its definition) among “grab” samples of patients plus, perhaps, normals. In addition to the biases of Level IV, these studies often include the sign or symptom result as part of a “**lead standard**,” resulting in a self-fulfilling prophesy. The results extravagantly over-estimate accuracy.

Other recent examples of *lead standard* in this sense can be found here and there, but the term is still far more commonly seen in discussions of safety standards for lead-exposure limits. You’re therefore probably safest using it only in contexts that also mention *gold standard*, like [in this statistics quiz](https://quizlet.com/28651010/statistics-for-psychosocial-research-i-flash-cards/).

Comment: This is the best answer, imho. I didn't know about the usage of "lead" standard, and I can't help but wonder why they didn't call it, "brass" standard, instead? Or "fool's gold" standard? Or maybe even the "tin" standard. I find "lead" a little ungainly (until I caught on, I was pronouncing it "leed", which had me a little confused, at first).

Comment: @Bread Think about the medieval alchemists’ forlorn quest to transmute lead into gold. In that regard the two elements were considered in some sense opposites.

Comment: One possible issue that may cause confusion with this phrase is that *lead* meaning the metal is a homonym of *lead*, meaning to go in front or the top or best example. If read incorrectly, it could lend a positive connotation where a negative one is desired. +1 anyway for being the parallel opposite as the asker requested.

Comment: This confirms what I suspected: that "gold standard" no longer suggests currency, William Jennings Bryant, or even Ron Paul, but that "gold" is now more understood as an adjective.

Comment: Interest only: When acceptance testing custom made small solar panels in China we established a test cell which all product should be superior to. We termed this our "lead standard". We coined the name ourselves as an obvious term given its function. The lead standard cell was used to calibrate a number of lead sub-standards which were used to set the testing machine at the start of each production shift. This compensated for light level variations in the test lamps, mounting jig variations etc.

Comment: That's a double negative, hence precisely what you don't want in the phrase asked for by the OP.  You **could** indeed say "Country has become the lead standard in Education..."

Comment: @KarlG - it is spectacularly common in English that words have more than one meaning.  "gold" is constantly used to mean "currency", and is also constantly used to mean the bullion object, and is also constantly used in "gold standard" (in the sense of "gold, silver, bronze" rankings).

Comment: @Fattie It is also "spectacularly common" in English for people not to over-analyse double negatives, and to understand the intention of phrases like these perfectly well.

Answer (score 65):

If the reason for your question is the apparent oxymoron in:

> Kazakhstan has become the *gold standard* for backwardness

then you could opt for an alternative word to express "perfect example" for which I propose **epitome**.  From [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/epitome):

> A person or thing that is a perfect example of a particular quality or type.

This seems imply the required extremeness of the characteristic, without implying a positive or negative tone to it.  Hence you could say:

> Kazakhstan has become the *epitome* of backwardness

If you want to reinforce the negative aspects of the characteristic being described, you could instead opt for **nadir** (likewise from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nadir)):

> The lowest or most unsuccessful point in a situation

Hence

> Kazakhstan has become the *nadir* of backwardness

Answer (score 43):

I think perhaps **poster child** or **poster boy** could work well. It is often used to to denote something that could be considered to be representative of unfavorable characteristics.

> The term poster child (sometimes poster boy or poster girl) originally
>   referred to a child afflicted by some disease or deformity whose
>   picture is used on posters or other media as part of a campaign to
>   raise money or enlist volunteers for a cause or organization. Such
>   campaigns may be part of an annual effort or event, and may include
>   the name and age of a specific child along with other personally
>   identifiable attributes.[1][2]
>
> The definition of "poster child" has since been expanded to a person
>   of any age whose attributes or behaviour are emblematic of a known
>   cause, movement, circumstance or ideal. Under this usage, the person
>   in question is labeled as an embodiment or archetype. This signifies
>   that the very identity of the subject is synonymous with the
>   associated ideal; or otherwise representative of its most favorable or
>   least favorable aspects.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poster_child

That said;

> **Benchmark** - a standard or point of reference against which things may be compared.

Is a generic term and could be applied either positively or negatively - depending on what the benchmark is in. Really any word that sets the thing in question as a prime example would work.

As an aside...

> "Recently, Kazakhstan has become the _____ for backwardness"

...is pretty offensive whatever the blank!

Comment: +1 for ***benchmark*** since the OP gave a sentence template using [Kazakhstandard] as a plimsoll line..

Comment: I'd also like to offer up [**Threshold of Disappointment**](https://www.schlockmercenary.com/pages/2017-movies/) from [Howard Tayler](http://howardtayler.com/), author of *[Schlock Mercenary](https://www.schlockmercenary.com/)*.

Comment: Argh. I think your "poster child" answer is pretty meh. I think your "benchmark" answer is perfect. But you've both suggestions in one answer , which means I can't vote on them separately. Please try and put separate suggestions in separate answers (though I know I'm guilty of doing exactly what you've done!).

Answer (score 15):

The *gold standard* only describes the standard, not that which it measures, so there's no reason it must apply only to the true, good, and beautiful. Thus the gold standard of:

> [dictatorship](http://www.pushkinhouse.org/author-interviews-2015-1/) (Stalin)
>
> [bad movies](https://www.google.de/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enDE701DE701&hl=de&ei=mh5kWtf6GoHewQK5-pKQAg&q=%22gold%20standard%20of%20bad%20movies%22&oq=%22gold%20standard%20of%20bad%20movies%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...20680.26939.0.27897.12.12.0.0.0.0.233.1631.0j10j1.11.0....0...1.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..1.3.530...30i10k1j0i22i30k1.159.iwg6nkkMwrU) (Wiseau's *The Room*)
>
> [evil](https://www.google.de/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enDE701DE701&hl=de&ei=kSNkWuLqDZDIsAfwipC4Aw&q=%22gold%20standard%20of%20evil%22&oq=%22gold%20standard%20of%20evil%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...8671.10753.0.11513.5.5.0.0.0.0.281.765.0j3j1.4.0....0...1.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..1.3.645...0i7i30k1j0i7i10i30k1j0i7i5i30k1.491.sUxfiCbuiKw) (Hitler or [Genghis Khan](https://www.reddit.com/r/TiADiscussion/comments/364d7p/why_is_hitler_the_gold_standard_for_evil/))
>
> [genocide](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/3nk2ij/why_was_hitler_so_obsessed_with_killing_the_jews/) (Hitler again)
>
> [kitsch](http://nymag.com/nymetro/arts/art/reviews/9172/) (Michael Jackson)
>
> [awfulness](https://books.google.de/books?id=3YM1DgAAQBAJ&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=%22gold%20standard%20of%20awfulness%22&source=bl&ots=nVIf5zwnFJ&sig=l39fUiTp0lOscTEFFjWnYSzqLzA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjf8IrSrejYAhUG26QKHS6ZAoAQ6AEwAXoECBEQAQ)  (*Footloose* the musical)

Now the usage to refer to Hitler et al. may set a new gold standard for bad taste — which got surprisingly few hits — but a gold standard for bad/failed art disturbs far less. In the context you suggest, *a new gold standard for backwardness*, i.e. the ultimate in backwardness, is perfectly reasonable.

---

***Meanwhile, back at the ranch...***

The origin of the metaphorical use of *gold standard* was, of course, the actual [gold standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_standard) by which a nation's currency was backed by a certain amount of the precious metal. The gold standard was not completely abandoned in the United States until 1971 under Nixon.

This, of course, did not stop anyone from using *gold standard* in a metaphorical sense, merely that the historical background has been jettisoned so that *gold* is no longer a noun (the actual metal) used attributively, but understood as an adjective that could be replaced by other substances, such as tchrist's *lead standard*, or a [*diamond*](https://www.google.de/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enDE701DE701&hl=de&ei=B7hlWqPkHYiVkwWAk6fIBw&q=%22diamond%20standard%20of%22&oq=%22diamond%20standard%20of%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3..0i8i7i30k1l3j0i8i30k1l2.7962.10347.0.11453.8.8.0.0.0.0.316.1525.0j4j2j1.7.0....0...1.1.64.mobile-gws-serp..2.6.1342...0i7i30k1.180.MyHTbnN0mP0) or [*platinum*](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22platinum%20standard%20of%22&rlz=1C9BKJA_enDE701DE701&oq=%22platinum%20standard%20of%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.17480j1j8&hl=de&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) standard, the latter two presumably exceeding a gold standard in value and excellence.

Comment: A controversial opinion, but one that’s backed up by research.

Comment: Again, the gold standard of kitsch is not the singer-songwriter, Michael Singer, but Koon's "tasteful" golden/porcelain statue of the artist. MJ was never really kitsch. [MJ and Bubbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Jackson_and_Bubbles) well worth seeing for its truly garish quality

Comment: “Koons’s Michael Jackson and Bubbles is a porcelain-and-gold mirage of _the entertainer who has not only become the gold standard of kitsch_ but also transformed himself into a living hallucination.“ “The entertainer who has...become the gold standard of kitsch” is clearly Michael Jackson.

Comment: Would that be *purposeful* genocide (Hitler), *uncaring* genocide (Stalin towards Ukrainians) or *gross stupidity* genocide (Mao in the Great Leap Forward)?  Because Stalin killed or allowed to starve 23M people, and 78M people died in Mao's Great Leap Forward.

Comment: I'm just demonstrating language use. I personally wouldn't use the expression because I consider it in bad taste, as I mentioned at the end of my answer.

Comment: OT, but when did Ed Wood's 'Plan 9 from Outer Space' stop being the gold standard in bad movies?

Comment: @mcalex: _The Room_ really is much worse. _Plan  9_, for instance, has a fairly coherent plot.

Answer (score 13):

> Recently, Kazakhstan has become the **new low** for backwardness, with news articles saying that Australia's education system or internet speed is worse than Kazakstan's.

The idiom, **to hit a new low**, is extremely derogatory, it suggests that someone or something has broken the record for appallingness.

For example, *we thought Bob's racism was shameful in the past but today he hit a new low*.

> ### ***low***
>
> **6.** countable noun [usually singular]
>   If something reaches a low of a particular amount or degree, that is the smallest it has ever been.
>   <sub>[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/low)</sub>

@professor_feather in the comments below suggested another expression, which I think is highly appropriate, the *[low bar](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/setting+a+low+bar)*.

> ### *set a low bar*
>
> To establish an expected, required, or desired (but ultimately constrictive) standard of quality 
>   <sub>Farlex Dictionary of Idioms</sub>

Here's a very recent example of usage

> "Frankly, at this point, the **bar is so low** that if he doesn't swear or doesn't malign a minority group, that's considered a huge success," Malmgren told CNBC.
>   (Source: CNBC  [2 Feb, 2018](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/02/02/trump-created-a-low-bar-environment-and-it-may-be-a-clever-strategy.html))

P.S.
If one searches the [Google news database](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lead%20standard%22&tbm=nws&ei=T4yJWszwLYT7UPSIhKAD&start=20&sa=N&biw=1309&bih=660&dpr=1.1), practically all the references to ***lead standard*** refer to the ***level of lead*** **present in the water system, fuel, air, soil, paint, and even electronic devices**.

For instance:

- *The lead standard needs updating, and the EPA knows that. In the future, we probably will see a higher standard."*
- *Snyder calls the current federal lead standard "dumb and dangerous." He says he doesn't want Michigan to wait until the federal rule is reviewed, which is not scheduled to happen until next year.*
- *28 Louisiana water systems would not meet proposed lead standard*
- *In 2008, the lead standard, or acceptable about of lead particulate in the air, changed from 1.5 micrograms per cubic meter to 0.15 micrograms per cubic meter - a 90 percent reduction.*

Answer (score 6):

> Recently, Kazakhstan has become the **go to example** for backwardness, with news articles saying that Australia's education system or internet speed is worse than Kazakhstan's.

The [Oxford English Dictionary defines](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/go-to) a **go to** as "a ... thing that may be relied on or is regularly sought out in a particular situation". 
In your use case, Kazakhstan is a go to as an example for demonstrating backwardness.

In the same vein:

> Recently, Kazakhstan has become the **de facto standard** for backwardness, with news articles saying that Australia's education system or internet speed is worse than Kazakstan's.

[Wikipedia defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto_standard) a **de facto standard** as "a custom or convention that has achieved a dominant position by public acceptance or market forces". By this definition, a de facto standard is similar to a gold standard, because it is dominant above other standards, but unlike a gold standard, it doesn't necessarily describe the "best" standard.

Comment: your answer needs citations to be creditable.. This may well be a good answer if you support it with sources.

Comment: A *de facto standard* hardly needs justification here, surely?

Comment: @Vaelus   yes, you have justified your answer well.. It does seem though that others  voted for answers before your edit.,

Answer (score 4):

I proffer **brown standard**.

Note that this is by no means a fixed-phrase, but is a play on the saying *gold standard*. It is not appropriate for formal discourse.

Comment: I've heard "brown standard" used before; definitely in informal discussion, as you can guess what "brown" refers to in terms of the standard it's setting. This was actually the first suggestion I thought of when I read the question!

Answer (score 3):

How about "***bottom of the barrel***", or more commonly "***scrape the bottom of the barrel***"? It implies the very worst example of something, acceptable (if at all) only because there are no other options available, or no way to sink lower.

Derived from the actual historical practice of scraping the last bits of food out of a storage barrel (see last source).

From [*The Free Dictionary*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bottom+of+the+barrel):

> **The cheapest, worst, or lowest quality.** Used to describe an item in a range of comparable products.
>
> *I know we need to save money, but this bottom-of-the-barrel computer barely even works.*
>
> *Our washing machine broke down after just two months of use, but that's what we get for buying the bottom of the barrel.*

From [*Dictionary.com*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/scrape-the-bottom-of-the-barrel):

> ***verb phrase***: To use one's **last and worst** resources; be forced to desperate measures : He scraped the bottom of the barrel when he proposed that topic for his paper (1942+)

From [*Wiktionary*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrape_the_bottom_of_the_barrel):

> *They must really have been **scraping the bottom of the barrel** if they couldn't find a better design than that.*
>
> Derived from the historical practice in the early United States of storing food in barrels; when food supplies ran low, only what was on the very bottom of the barrel remained, and had to be removed by scraping.

Answer (score 2):

I think **touchstone** captures a similar meaning to "gold standard" without the positive implication.

It works particularly well in your example, as it indicates that *other people* are using Kazakstan as a reference point, without sounding like it is *you* who is making the assertion about Kazkhstan's backwardness.

> Recently, Kazakhstan has become a *touchstone* for backwardness ...

Answer (score 2):

## Plumb new depths

> If you say that something plumbs new depths, you mean that it is worse than all the things of its kind that have existed before, even though some of them have been very bad.  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-plumb-new-depths)

Literally it means you've managed to find some ocean which is deeper than all the ocean you measured before.

Examples:

> US house prices plumb new depths. House prices in 11 of the biggest US cities have fallen to their lowest point since the bust of 2006-7 – in Las Vegas, the fall is even worse. [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2011/feb/22/us-housing-market-plumbs-new-depths)
>
> When Allardyce suggested -- without a trace of irony or self-awareness after the 4-0 defeat at Tottenham in the previous match -- that Everton may need to be more boring and less adventurous, the statement was both bewildering and seemingly impossible. But this seventh successive game without a win proved Allardyce true to his word as boredom and a lack of adventure did in fact plumb new depths. [ESPN](http://www.espn.in/football/club/everton/368/blog/post/3355593/sam-allardyce-lacks-answers-as-everton-sink-lower-in-draw-with-west-brom)
>
> Gang members show no sympathy for victims. Indeed, MS-13 members proudly repeat their motto, “Kill, rape and control.” Many gangs plumb new depths of depravity in an effort to live up to that motto. [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/01/19/opinion/getting-tough-on-sex-traffickers.html)

Your example might be phrased as:

> Recently, Kazakhstan has **plumbed new depths** in backwardness, with news articles saying that Australia's education system or internet speed is worse than Kazakstan's.

Comment: The meaning here is sound, but I don't think it works well in the example sentence. If Australia's speed is worse, then it is *Australia* that is plumbing new depths, whereas the depths Kazakhstan plumbed are now superseded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the expression ***[black sheep](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/black-sheep)*** to refer to the worst member for having  done something bad:

> a member of a family or group regarded as not so respectable or successful as the rest.

(Collins Dictionary)

“Recently, Kazakhstan has become the black sheep  for backwardness, with news articles saying that Australia's education system or internet speed is worse than Kazakstan's.”

Comment: 'WED is the black sheep among dictionaries' doesn't sound too natural.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - yes, don’t use it referring to dictionaries.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you think it's the preposition? I'd probably suggest using 'of' instead of among if using black sheep, patterned after phrases like "black sheep of the family."

Comment: @Tonepoet I think the metaphor is normally reserved for people. The Kazakstan example obviously involves people at a distance, as would examples referring to organisations. 'Deadly nightshade is the black sheep of the Solanaceae family' sounds at best quirky. 'The OED' (of course, the term is inappropriate anyway here) is probably too distant, third hand (though 'WED staff are the black sheep among dictionary compilers' probably works).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - the metaphor  is and can be used for anything in reference to a larger group, that’s what metaphors are for!!

Comment: Your last comment doesn't recognise mixed / ill-fitting metaphors. 'John's a tiger' works better than 'That chihuahua is a tiger'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - that’s just a personal perception of what fits best. A metaphor is a metaphor.

Comment: 'The metaphor is and can be used for anything ...' and '[T]hat's what metaphors are for' must default to 'It is acceptable to use any metaphor wherever you choose'. That's nonsense. [Professor RR Provine](https://www.edge.org/response-detail/12028) gives the true picture:  'Metaphor is a powerful cognitive tool, which, like all models, clarifies thinking when appropriate, but constrains it when inappropriate.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - and who decides that black sheep is inappropriate ? You?

Comment: Your Collins definition limits usage to a family or other group **of people**, as do other dictionaries. 'The corvette was the black sheep of the Elizabethan navy' sounds distinctly unnatural.

Comment: Edwin may just have a point about it being primarily restricted to people, but rather than debating about it with him in the comments, I think it would be more productive for you to prove your point using evidence, if you can. Implementing illustrative quotations, especially from respected sources, that serve as evidence to your claims may serve as an example of how it is used effectively in other contexts, or using Google nGrams to show that usage of it in an extended sense is not insignificant can only help to make your answer more convincing to future voters.

Comment: @Tonepoet - Edwin has already downvoted my answer, as most of my other answers as a matter of fact. That’s it.

Comment: I'm sure the metaphor has been used in conjunction with countries or/and institutions (hospitals, schools, gov't departments,  etc.) before.

Comment: The belladonna reference would actually be quite appropriate, since *[Solanaceæ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanaceae)* is a *Family*, but alas breaks down because the entire *[Hyoscyameae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyoscyameae) Tribe* are toxic :o)

Comment: This could work in some contexts. For example: https://basketball.realgm.com/analysis/247994/Book-Excerpt-How-The-Warriors-Went-From-Black-Sheep-To-Gold-Standard

Comment: @Mari-LouA - thanks for your support, but Edwin chose to be strictly prescriptivist in this case. If you are a black sheep you  must be a human being. That’s it!!

Comment: In your shoes, I would have found references to support my answer. You haven't which might make users wonder why. Edwin knows he isn't infallible, look how many users have upvoted the comment disagreeing his earlier one underneath the OP's. We all make blunders, just some of us are more willing than others to admit them. This does not exclude you.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - do you really think he is interested in seeing my research? You are missing the point..this is a mod issue.

Comment: He's not a mod. And no one else has upvoted your answer, so that should give you food for thought.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -         Well, the answer got an upvote and  Edwin downvoted. The metaphor is correct, maybe users were distracted by the trail of comments and by the other answers.